# Difference between a REPLACE statement and WHERE when replaceing characters in a field?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I apologize if this has been asked before. I have a field called `POSITION` which is `VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)`. If I use the statement

```
update SA_ASSET
set POSITION = REPLACE(POSITION, 'SOLIDS BLDG', 'SOLIDS STRUCTURE')
where location = 'SOUTH COUNTY REGIONAL AWT PLAN';
```

I come up with an

> ORA-12899: value too large for column "SYNERGEN"."SA_ASSET"."POSITION"
>   (actual: 21, maximum: 20) error.

If I do the same thing with a WHERE statement it works:

```
update SA_ASSET
set POSITION = 'SOLIDS STRUCTURE'
where location = 'SOUTH COUNTY REGIONAL AWT PLAN'
AND POSITION = 'SOLIDS BLDG';
```

The length of the replacement is the same (15 chars and 15 bytes) but something is different using the REPLACE statement. This has happened on several occasions where the char/byte count has been less than 20. We are using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production if that makes any difference Has anyone come across this and have an answer as to why?

Comment: It seems unlikely from the data but what is the setting for NLS_LANGUAGE and NLS_CHARACTERSET.  By any chance is there data with accents?

Comment: You probably have a row where `positions <> 'SOLIDS BLDG'` but where `'SOLIDS BLDG'` is a substring. Something line `'SOLIDS BLDG 20000'` where the replacement, `'SOLIDS STRUCTURE 20000'` is too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is straightforward after replacing your data is too big for column.

Data (example):

```
POSITION = 'SOLIDS BLDG SOME T'             -- 18 characters
LOCATION = 'SOUTH COUNTY REGIONAL AWT PLAN'


update SA_ASSET
set POSITION = REPLACE(POSITION, 'SOLIDS BLDG', 'SOLIDS STRUCTURE')
where location = 'SOUTH COUNTY REGIONAL AWT PLAN';
```

Then you tried to `SET`:

```
'SOLIDS STRUCTURE SOME T' > 20 characters
```

Answer (score 2):

Your statements are semantically different. In failing statement you update more rows than in the first one, due to the working one having extra filtering condition (`AND POSITION = 'SOLIDS BLDG'`).

You could have a row with a `POSITION` being like `'SOLIDS BLDG WHATEVER'` (which is already 20 characters long), for which a replace command will return `REPLACE('SOLIDS BLDG WHATEVER', 'SOLIDS BLDG', 'SOLIDS STRUCTURE') ==> 'SOLIDS STRUCTURE WHATEVER'`, which is apparently longer than 20. In the second statement this is not happening as you are explicitly filtering `'SOLIDS BLDG WHATEVER'` from being updated.

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE replaces each occurrence of the pattern in your text string, it doesn't overwrite it. So, if your original string is 20 characters, and you want to replace a 4 character phrase with a 5 character phrase, then you're going to end up with a string that's 21 characters.

If your column is set to 20 characters wide, then you're going to end up with the ORA-12899 error that you experienced. E.g.:

```
create table test1 (col1 number,
                    col2 varchar2(10));

insert into test1 (col1, col2)
values (1, 'abcdefghij');

commit;

select col1,
       col2,
       replace(col2, 'j', 'xy') new_col2,
       length(replace(col2, 'j', 'xy')) length_new_col2
from   test1
where  col1 = 1;

      COL1 COL2       NEW_COL2             LENGTH_NEW_COL2
---------- ---------- -------------------- ---------------
         1 abcdefghij abcdefghixy                       11

update test1
set col2 = replace(col2, 'j', 'xy')
where col1 = 1;
```

> ORA-12899: value too large for column "SCHEMA"."TEST1"."COL2" (actual: 11, maximum: 10)